# Need help on getting google map Key for map application

Tags: xamarin.android

I visit the below link to get Google map Key

Visit https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

a)  have create a Project in Google Api console

b)  have created a SHA1 certificate fingerprint base on google's below insturction

```
    keytool -list -v -keystore mystore.keystore
```

mystore.keystore refer to:   C:.....  Xamarin\Mono for Android\debug.keystore"

Problems :

P1)  Where to get package name in Xamarin to create Google map key base on this format:

One SHA1 certificate fingerprint and package name (separated by a semicolon) per line.

Example:

45:B5:E4:6F:36:AD:0A:98:94:B4:02:66:2B:12:17:F2:56:26:A0:E0;com.example

2) is this Map key required when I test the map app in emulator?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1)

Within Visual Studio:

- Right click your project > Properties
- Click the Android Manifest tab on the left.
- Package name field is what you are looking for.

If you see the message "No AndroidManifest.xml found. Click to add one.

Within Xamarin Studio:

- Right click your project > Options.
- Navigate to the Build / Android Application section.
- Package name field is what you are looking for.

2)

Yes you need a map key to test the app in the emulator.

Comment: Thanks. new to google api console. now I use testing App1 package name to get map Key, what if I the final app is App2. can I use the map Key?

Comment: From: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start
"Maps API keys are linked to specific certificate/package pairs, rather than to users or applications. You only need one key for each certificate, no matter how many users you have for an application. Applications that use the same certificate can use the same API key. However, the recommended practice is to sign each of your applications with a different certificate and get a different key for each one."